# Deserialize XML to C# 2D List

Tags: c#, xml, generic-list

I am trying to convert my XML document to a C# 2D List. But when i do this the list is empty...

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <levels>
    <level ID="0">
      <theItem ID="0">
        <type>Corner</type>
        <rotation>180</rotation>
        <positionX>-5.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-2.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
      <theItem ID="1">
        <type>TripleBar</type>
        <rotation>270</rotation>
        <positionX>-4.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-2.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
      <theItem ID="2">
        <type>Corner</type>
        <rotation>270</rotation>
        <positionX>-3.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-2.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
      <theItem ID="3">
        <type>Bar</type>
        <rotation>0</rotation>
        <positionX>-5.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-1.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
    </level>
  </levels>
</data>
```

And this are my classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class theItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("rotation")]
    public int rotation { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("positionX")]
    public int positionX { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("positionY")]
    public int positionY { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class level
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("level")]
    public List<theItem> theItems { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("data")]
public class data
{
    [XmlArray("levels")]
    [XmlArrayItem("level")]
    public List<level> levels { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my deserializer code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("LevelData.xml"))
        {
            data info = (data)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            List<level> levels = info.levels;
        }
```

The problem is that when i try to check every list's length, my first list is having the length 1 wich is normal, but the second is = 0...
What I am trying to say is that I want to get a list like this:
List < level > levels and in every level to be a List < theItem > theItems with the theItem elements and every theItem to have its content like in the XML file...
I tryed multiple ways but i didn't found solution for my problem. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Btw. "-5.5" is not an int.

Comment: Note that [Serializable] attribute **is not** anyhow related to XML serialization.

Comment: My mistake here,i changed to float...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might work. Change your level class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class level
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("level")]
    public List<theItem> items { get; set; }
}
```

And then change your xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <levels>
    <level ID="0">
      <items>
      <theItem ID="0">
        <type>Corner</type>
        <rotation>180</rotation>
        <positionX>-5.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-2.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
      <theItem ID="1">
        <type>TripleBar</type>
        <rotation>270</rotation>
        <positionX>-4.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-2.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
      <theItem ID="2">
        <type>Corner</type>
        <rotation>270</rotation>
        <positionX>-3.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-2.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
      <theItem ID="3">
        <type>Bar</type>
        <rotation>0</rotation>
        <positionX>-5.5</positionX>
        <positionY>-1.5</positionY>
      </theItem>
    </items>
    </level>
  </levels>
</data>
```

**Edit:**

As Ondrej correctly points out: Most of your position values cannot be serialized as ints. So changing these into floats will work better:

```
[XmlElement("positionX")]
public float positionX { get; set; }
[XmlElement("positionY")]
public float positionY { get; set; }
```

**Edit 2: Simpler solution**

In your original XML file You're using `<level>` as a list of `<theItem>`, so you have to update the objects to reflect that. You can simply do this by making level extend a List like this and use the original XML structure:

```
[Serializable]
public class level : List<theItem>
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When dealing with deserialization changing the data format is *not* the right way to go, unless it's truly impossible to handle.

Comment: Now it's working, changed the theItem class's variables from int to float and added to my XML <items></items> and also changed the level class 
[XmlArray("items")] and the list's name to items and everything works fine now! Thanks!

Comment: @OndrejTucny You're right. Though in this case I think it was the easiest solution. If someone comes up with a better answer I'll be sure to upvote it.

Comment: I'm on mobile, can't try anything, but I'd guess it's just a matter o proper attributes + the int->float issue. Your answer goes the right direction but I'd get rid of the extra <items> tag.

Comment: I will try without the <items> tag to see how it will work, if it won't work i will add it agait, but i think is more about the int->float issue

Comment: I updated the answer to include the int/float issue. If @TGPArcher confirms that the <items> tag is unnecessary I'll edit it further.

Comment: I tested the second edit, removed the "items" tag and and everuthing works fine. So thank you guys a lot, saved me a lot of time, happy new year;)